# Replacing a string with a capture group in Swift 3

Tags: regex, swift

I have the following string: "@[1484987415095898:274:Page Four]" and I want to capture the name, so I wrote to following regexp
`@\[[\d]+:[\d]+:(.*)]`
It seems to be working, but now I am struggling to understand how to replace the previous string with the capture group one.
i.e
"Lorem ipsum @[1484987415095898:274:Page Four] dolores" ->
 "Lorem ipsum Page Four dolores"

Note, I saw how to get the capture group out using [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789953/swift-3-how-do-i-extract-captured-groups-in-regular-expressions)
however, how to I find the original string this was extracted from and replace it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 - How do I extract captured groups in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789953/swift-3-how-do-i-extract-captured-groups-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: It is not about extracting groups here, but about how to replace with them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to replace the whole match with the `$1` replacement backreference that holds the contents captured with the first capturing group.

Besides, I'd advise to write the `[\d]` as `\d` to avoid misinterpretations of the character class unions if you decide to expand the pattern later. Also, it is safer to use `.*?`, lazy dot matching, to get to the first `]` rather than to the last `]` (if you use `.*` greedy variation). However, that depends on the real requirements.

Use either of the following:

```
let txt = "Lorem ipsum @[1484987415095898:274:Page Four] dolores"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@\\[\\d+:\\d+:(.*?)\\]", options:nil, error: nil)
let newString = regex!.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(txt, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(txt)), withTemplate: "$1")
print(newString)
// => Lorem ipsum Page Four dolores
```

or

```
let txt = "Lorem ipsum @[1484987415095898:274:Page Four] dolores"
let newString = txt.replacingOccurrences(of: "@\\[\\d+:\\d+:(.*?)]", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
print(newString)
// => Lorem ipsum Page Four dolores
```

Comment: Or simply `let newString = txt.replacingOccurrences(of: "@\\[[\\d]+:[\\d]+:(.*)]", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, that is a better notation, thanks. I still prefer my pattern that is cleaner and should be safer in case there are several matches on the same line.

Comment: If you prefer your use of `NSRegularExpression` (which has many benefits), then why change your answer?

Comment: @rmaddy I thought you criticized my notation :)

Comment: Not at all. I was simply pointing out an alternate approach. Your use of `NSRegularExpression` has it's benefits. My suggestion is good if it's a one-time use.

Comment: Which one would work if there could be more than one occasion of the regular expression in the string? "Lorem ipsum @[1484987415095898:274:Page Four] dolores @[1484987415095898:274:Page Six] "

Comment: Both approaches are basically the same and both will replace all occurrences. BTW - another option to replacing the `.*` with `.*?` is to replace the `.*` with `[^]]*`.

Comment: @rmaddy I am biased in this specific case to use `.*?`: 1) the `]` inside the character class must be escaped in ICU regex flavor and overescaping makes a pattern difficult to read, 2) If OP needs to precise the context of the trailing `]`, the `[^]]` will turn out too restrictive.

Comment: @YoavSchwartz These 2 snippets are equivalent in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you guys. It seems I always get close with the Regex but it's never the right one :) Thanks for your help!