# Non-fixed width positive lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match the height field in the svg tag of an svg file that can look like this (multiline):

```
<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
version="1.1"
id="svg2"
height="1052.36220472"
width="744.094488189">
```

This regex gives me almost what I want:

```
/(<svg[^<>]*height=")(\d*\.\d*)("[^<>]*>)/ms
```

I'd like to match only the float value for the height (1052.36220472), so lookahead/lookbehind seems the way to go, but I cannot use non-fixed width lookbehinds, so

```
/(?<=<svg[^<>]*height=")(\d*\.\d*)(?="[^<>]*>)/ms
```

does not work - what can I do instead?

I want to use the match for replacement within php, with the preg_replace() function.

Comment: Just access the second group value when using `/(<svg[^<>]*height=")(\d*\.\d*)("[^<>]*>)/`. If it is written in Swift, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789953/swift-3-how-do-i-extract-captured-groups-in-regular-expressions).

Comment: What language or tool is it?

Comment: Intended for use in php with the preg_replace() function, added that to the post.

Comment: Use `\K` then: `<svg[^<>]*height="\K[^"]*`

Comment: When you say 'only the float value', do you mean just the digits after the decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by revo (thanks!), `\K` does the job:

```
/(?<=<svg[^<>]*height=")\K(\d*\.\d*)(?="[^<>]*>)/ms
```

Will only match the decimal number and drop the rest of the svg tag.