# Escaping Regex with special characters in Swift

Tags: swift, regex

I have a relatively complex regex that I need to run in Swift. Originally was:

`"typedef\W+struct\W+{([^}]*)}\W+(\w+);"`

You can see the pattern working in JS [here](https://regexr.com/4819o).

To make it compile in Swift I escaped the backslashes to:

`"typedef\\W+struct\\W+{([^}]*)}\\W+(\\w+);"`

On runtime the expression fails to compile with `2048` error. I tried escaping other characters too and tried also `escapedPatternForString` but without luck. Is there a script to convert JS regexs to Swift? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `"typedef\\W+struct\\W+\\{([^}]*)\\}\\W+(\\w+);"`

Comment: you are right, escaping only the "{" and "}" more, doesn't fail!

Comment: Note that `escapedPatternForString` is good when you need to pass a literal string into a regex pattern. It should not be used against the *regex* pattern itself.

Comment: Yeah, I was it escaped every special chars. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape both `{` and `}` that are *outside* of a character class:

```
let rx = "typedef\\W+struct\\W+\\{([^}]*)\\}\\W+(\\w+);"
```

A quick demo:

```
let rx = "typedef\\W+struct\\W+\\{([^}]*)\\}\\W+(\\w+);"
let str = "typedef: struct { something } text;"
print(str.range(of: rx, options: .regularExpression) != nil) 
// => true
```

When the `{` and `}` are inside a character class they may stay unescaped (as in `[^}]`).

Using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51384977/3832970) (answer by [Confused Vorlon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256935/confused-vorlon)), you may get the first match with all capturing groups:

```
extension NSTextCheckingResult {
    func groups(testedString:String) -> [String] {
        var groups = [String]()
        for i in  0 ..< self.numberOfRanges
        {
            let group = String(testedString[Range(self.range(at: i), in: testedString)!])
            groups.append(group)
        }
        return groups
    }
}

let str = "typedef: struct { something } text;"
let rx = "typedef\\W+struct\\W+\\{([^}]*)\\}\\W+(\\w+);"
let MyRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: rx)
if let match = MyRegex.firstMatch(in: str, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count)) {
     let groups = match.groups(testedString: str)
     print(groups)
}
// => ["typedef: struct { something } text;", " something ", "text"]
```

Comment: @Nuthinking There are a lot of questions regarding getting captures from matches. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40040472/3832970), for example. Do you need to get just the contents of a single capturing group?