# How to split numeric and substring from main string in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring, numeric

I have a case where I need to separate the numeric value and other substring from the main given string.

Suppose the main string is `350.55kph`.
Then my desired result is `350.55` as a numeric value and `kph` is other substring.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```swift
let string = "350kph"
let stringArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
for item in stringArray {
    if let integer = Int(item) {
        print("integer: \(integer)")
    }
}
```

Note: This would work for strings containing multiple `Int` eg: "350km per 2hr". You would only require:

```swift
let string = "350kph"
let integer = Int(string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined())
print("integer: \(integer)")
```

Okay I saw your edits, here's how to decimals, (there are other ways too):

```swift
let string = "350.55kph"
let components = string.components(separatedBy: ".")
let decimalPart = Int(components.last!.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()) ?? 0
let double = Double("\(components.first ?? "0").\(decimalPart)")
print(decimalPart,"double: \(double)")
```

Other way: You can modify the `CharecterSet` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: just made an edit to my question. the values can be anything float or double like. 350.55kph.

Comment: @MaulikPandya check now 

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression would probably work. Something like `([0-9.]+)([A-Za-z]+)` which will extract it into two groups: 1 one with numeric part, the other with the unit.

There's a few options here on how to work with those groups: [Swift 3 - How do I extract captured groups in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789953/swift-3-how-do-i-extract-captured-groups-in-regular-expressions)