# Swift Regex to check if String is Amount format (2x, 3x,...)

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string

I would like to check if a given `String` is in a *amount* format. A few examples for a better understanding:

**Should return `true`:**

> 2x

> 31x

> 3x abcd

**Should return `false`:**

> 2x3

> 3xabc

> asdf3x

So in general: it has to start with a number (0-9), can be more digits. Right after the number a "x"/"X" should follow and after the "x"/"X" should be the end or a white space.

I am struggling to get this done.. This is what I tried:

```
func isAmountFormat() -> Bool {
    return self.matches("[0-9]+[X,x]")
}
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You could add word boundaries `\b[0-9]+[Xx]\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that gives `invalid escape sequence in literal` .

Comment: Then perhaps `\\b[0-9]+[Xx]\\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think this is working. One more thing: Do you know how I can extract the number before the x from a given String in this format??

Comment: Using a capture group `\\b([0-9]+)[Xx]\\b` see https://regex101.com/r/Y2DNT9/1

Comment: never used that before, how would I do that in Swift?

Comment: My swift knowlegde is at a minimum, but [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789953/swift-3-how-do-i-extract-captured-groups-in-regular-expressions) for example has some examples.

Comment: @Thefourthbird one last thing! "0x" should not be valid, but "1x" or "100x" should be valid. What do I have to change then ?

Comment: Use `"(?i)\\b[1-9][0-9]*x\\b"`. Could you describe what you mean by "amount format" to get an answer?

Comment: thanks guys! It is working now as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"(?i)\\b[1-9][0-9]*x\\b"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGJPd8/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag (in case you cannot pass the `.caseInsensitive` in your current regex matching method)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `[0-9]*` - any zero or more digits
- `x` - an `X` or `x`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See a [Swift snippet](https://rextester.com/VXK32959):

```swift
let test = "3x abcd"
if test.range(of: "\\b[1-9][0-9]*x\\b", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) != nil {
    print("Matched")
} else {
   print("No match")
}
```

Note that if the match should occur at the start of the string, you may compile the regex object with the `.anchored` option, or replace the first `\\b` with `^`.